# runnable jar - not writing text file

Tags: java, executable-jar, runnable

Runnable jar file not producing output to ouput file.

The code works fine when running in eclipse.
This code writes some data to a text file.
Please help.
I created the runnable jar file using export option.

Thanks

Comment: post your code to help others.

Comment: search on google about how to create jar file in eclips

Answer (score 0):

If the code is running correctly in Eclipse then there is no problem in code.You have to first build the jar using Ant or Maven.Then you can place all the dependencies(jars) in the appropriate directory by creating a lib folder.Then place your jar in that same directory with all the config files.Then open your terminal(Command), go to the appropriate path and try 'java -jar YourProjctName.jar'.

Comment: After removing database related processing, its working. May be acees for database opration only given when runs within eclipse in my workplace.